# Lyx KOMA-script page header

Tags: header-footer, lyx, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I am working on a book using `KOMA-script` in LYX 2.3. The first two chapters (Preface and Introduction_ are unnumbered. I can add them to the Table of Contents using e.g.,  `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}`. However, the page header does not show the chapter name.

I have tried adding `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}` to the LaTeX preamble and `\pagehead {Preface}` to the text. This results in error  message:

> "Undefined control sequence" when trying to output pdf.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

With document class `scrbook` you can use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` and `\chapter` for unnumbered chapters in front matter.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\mainmatter
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `\addchap` for unnumbered chapters.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Preface}
\lipsum
\addchap{Introduction}
\lipsum
\chapter{Foo}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```